# Insertar, Consultar y Modificar una Imagen en C# y SQL

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms

He creado una pequeña aplicación de prueba en la que deseo insertar el nombre de un empleado y una foto adjunta, para ello tengo el siguiente formulario...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y estoy trabajando con esta pequeña base de datos...

```
create table Empleado
(ID int identity (1,1) not null, Nombre varchar(50) not null, Foto image null, constraint pk_ID primary key (ID))
```

Tengo un "PictureBox" para que el usuario cargue la respectiva foto asociado al registro para eso he programado el botón de búsqueda de la siguiente manera.

```
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(dialog.FileName);
        }
```

Mi aplicación funciona bien pero el gran inconveniente que tengo es la incógnita de saber ¿como puedo guardar la imagen que el usuario a cargado en el pictureBox en mi base de datos y también como puedo mostrar la imagen en el pictureBox o en mi DataGridView al hacer la consulta de los registros?

```
         var consulta = "select ID, Nombre from Empleado";
        var c = new SqlConnection("Data Source = DESKTOP-3A3MBDC\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = Imagen; Integrated Security = True"); 
        var adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(consulta, c);

        var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adaptador);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        adaptador.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Este es el código en el cual muestro lo registros en mi DataGridView, como ven en este punto no realizo un Select al campo "foto" de mi tabla Empleado ya que desconozco como guardarla en primer lugar.

Tengo mis respectivas clases para Guardar el registro y Modificarlo

Método para agregar

```
public static int Agregar(ClsEmpleado pEmpleado)
    {
        int retorno = 0;
        using (SqlConnection conn = ClsConexion.ObtenerConexion())
        {
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Insert into Empleado values ('{0}','{1}')", pEmpleado.Nombre,pEmpleado.Foto), conn);
            retorno = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return retorno;
        }
```

Método para Modificar

```
public static int Modificar(ClsEmpleado empleado)
    {
        int retorno = 0;
        using (SqlConnection conn = ClsConexion.ObtenerConexion())
        {
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Update Empleado set Nombre = '{0}' where ID = {1}", empleado.Nombre, empleado.Id), conn);
            retorno = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        return retorno;
    }
```

Método para llevar los datos al formulario principal para modificarlos

```
        public static ClsEmpleado ObtenerEmpleado(Int32 pId){
        using (SqlConnection conn = ClsConexion.ObtenerConexion())
        {
            ClsEmpleado empleado = new ClsEmpleado();

            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Select Nombre from Empleado where ID = {0}", pId), conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                empleado.Nombre = reader.GetString(0);
            }



            conn.Close();
            return empleado;
        }

    }
```

En conclusión lo que deseo saber es como guardar la imagen en mi base de datos y como ver esa imagen (ya sea en un datagridview o en un picturebox) en caso de consultar un registro junto a los datos y como podría modificar esa misma imagen para cambiarla por otra en caso de ser necesario, he leído un poco que se tiene que convertir la imagen a bytes o binarios (no recuerdo muy bien) pero la verdad no termino de comprender como funciona dicho proceso

Por cierto, esta es mi clase empleado con sus propiedades.

```
    public class ClsEmpleado
    {
    private int id;
    private string nombre;
    private byte foto;

    public byte Foto
    {
        get { return foto; }
        set { foto = value; }
    }

    public string Nombre
    {
        get { return nombre; }
        set { nombre = value; }
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }


    public ClsEmpleado(){}

    public ClsEmpleado(int pid, string pnombre, byte pfoto)
    {
        this.id = pid;
        this.nombre = pnombre;
        this.Foto = pfoto;
    }


}
```

tengo una propiedad llamada "foto" la cual tiene un tipo de dato "byte" esto lo hice para intentar obtener algún resultado, sin éxito.

Answer (score 1):

Muy buenas Sasori,
Como bien dices las imagenes puedes guardarlas como un flujo de bytes.
Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
    try
    {
           // Objetos de conexión y comando
           System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source=
    (local);Initial Catalog=store;Integrated Security=SSPI");
           System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();

           // Estableciento propiedades
           cmd.Connection = conn;
           cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Products VALUES (@id, @name, @quantity, @price, @image)";

          // Creando los parámetros necesarios
           cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
           cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar);
           cmd.Parameters.Add("@quantity", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
           cmd.Parameters.Add("@price", System.Data.SqlDbType.SmallMoney);
           cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", System.Data.SqlDbType.Image);

           // Asignando los valores a los atributos
           cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = int.Parse(idBox.Text);
           cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = nameBox.Text;
           cmd.Parameters["@quantity"].Value = int.Parse(quantityBox.Text);
           cmd.Parameters["@price"].Value = float.Parse(priceBox.Text);

           // Asignando el valor de la imagen

           // Stream usado como buffer
           System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
           // Se guarda la imagen en el buffer
           pictureBox.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
           // Se extraen los bytes del buffer para asignarlos como valor para el 
           // parámetro.
           cmd.Parameters["@image"].Value = ms.GetBuffer();

           conn.Open();
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           conn.Close();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
 }
```

Para mas información he sacado este ejemplo de la [ayuda de microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb972266.aspx)

**PASAR BYTE[] A IMAGEN**

Un ejemplo de como convertir el array de bytes a imagen:

```
 //convert bytearray to image
    public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
        {
            return Image.FromStream(mStream);
        }
    }
```

Como puedes ver al crear las consultas se usan **parametros** con tipo, te recomiendo que uses parámetros en lugar de rellenar las consultas como he podido ver en tu código.
Si tienes cualquier duda pon un comentario e intentaré resolverla.

Un saludo y espero que te sirva

Comment: Este ejemplo ya lo había tratado y el inconveniente que tengo con el es que yo tengo una clase en la que tengo mi método "Agregar" y al tratar de llamar al "PictureBox" no puedo hacerlo ya que es un control de mi formulario y desconozco como poder llamarlo a mi clase "Agregar"

Comment: Tendrás que guardar los bytes (la imagen la transfomas en un `bytes[]`) en tu clase empleado y luego en agregar acceder a ellos desde el empleado.

Comment: Ya logre guardar la foto en la DB, ahora ¿como puedo verla en un pictureBox o en un Datagrid junto con los datos del empleado?

Comment: Añado como pasar de byte[] a imagen en la respuesta.